# Flamingo's Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 ... wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2516

Tags: fatal-error

I’m exporting a report on Flamingo but receiving this error:

**Fatal error**: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in **/home/storage/.../public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php** on line **2516**

I updated memory_limit on PHP.ini top 512M and server says that this is an error on application, not on the server.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is Flamingo?

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's pretty common that this error is due to a recursive loop, not to memory lack.. so I suggest to check the integrity of data first. Increasing memory limit will never solve the problem in these cases

Comment: Thanks, Andrea. Can you give a direction on how to check this integrity? I can access phpMyAdmin, but don't know much about SQL.

Comment: If it were an infinite loop problem I'd expect a higher 'tried to allocate' than 72 bytes. It looks to me like something's using just a little bit too much memory. 'Exporting a report' sounds like the sort of thing that could naturally use a lot of memory.

Comment: Ok... I'm gonna try to deactivate some plugins that may be using too much memory at this time. If I succeed I'll let you know.

Comment: SOLVED: After the precious comments, I deactivated some plugins, and after I do this to Wordfence, the Export on Flamingo worked. Thank you very much!